# Why does unlocking a unique_lock cause my program to crash?

Tags: c++, multithreading, locking, mutex

I am running into some odd behavior regarding `unique_lock`. After creating it, I try to call unlock, but it crashes my program. I have created a minimal example that consistently crashes on the unlock function (used gdb to confirm).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <mutex>
#include <thread>
#include <chrono>

std::mutex myMutex;

void lockMe()
{
  std::unique_lock lock(myMutex);
  std::cout << "Thread\n";
}

int main()
{
  std::unique_lock lock(myMutex);
  auto c = std::thread(lockMe);
  std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));
  std::cout << "Main\n";
  myMutex.unlock();
  c.join();
  return 0;
}
```

Can anyone explain why this is happening?

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/unique_lock/unlock - throws if the mutex is not locked, which it won't be as you unlocked it.

Comment: You do know that there's no need to manually unlock a mutex that has been locked by a `unique_lock`?

Comment: Can you explain why you are unlocking the mutex explicitly? Also, can you say what you believe the word "unique" means in the context of its use in "unique_lock"? The problem here lies in your misunderstanding of some basic concept, but it is unclear what concept it is that you're misinformed on, so tell us more and we can disabuse you of your misapprehension.

Comment: That was actually a mistake and indeed is the fault. In the actual problem though, I am calling the lock to unlock instead, and that is what is causing the error.

Comment: In particular, your question doesn't match your code. Your question is "why does unlocking a unique lock crash?" but you are not unlocking a unique lock. You're unlocking a mutex. Can you explain the discrepancy between the question and the code?

Comment: You are correct. I'm going to either try to recreate what's happening to me again and delete this post, or edit this post with the correct information.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By creating `std::unique_lock lock(myMutex);` you are granting mutex lock / unlock control to the lock object. if you manually unlock the mutex while it is still under control of the `lock` object you will violate that constraint and `lock` destructor will perform a double unlock attempt.

It is similar to all the RAII wrappers - once you grant resource control to RAII object you should not interfere with it by manually disposing of the resource.

Note that `std::unique_lock` offers a method to unlock the locked mutex prior to scope end that won't cause problems:

```
lock.unlock();
```

Comment: lock.unlock();  is precisely what crashes with my code